# Slow background image zoom with roll over on hover

Tags: css

i have this code:

```
.box1{
background-size:cover !important; 
height:450px;
width:450px;
background-image:url('https://s10.postimg.org/cqrkj63s9/02_preview-veicoli-industriali_800x800.jpg');

}
.box1:hover {
transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
background-size:200% 200% !important; 
background-image:url('https://s10.postimg.org/xcaxotaqx/02_preview-veicoli-industriali_800x800_blu.jpg');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/52eosap0/

but not work.

I can use only one div with image background.

help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 pseudo elements for the images

change on hover the opacity of both, one going from 1 to 0 and the other going from 0 to 1.

And background-size is not animatable, change the whole dimension of the pseudo with scale instead

```css
.box1 {
  background-size: cover !important;
  height: 450px;
  width: 450px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box1:before,
.box1:after {
  content: "";
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.box1:before {
  background-image: url('https://s10.postimg.org/cqrkj63s9/02_preview-veicoli-industriali_800x800.jpg');
}

.box1:after {
  opacity: 0;
  background-image: url('https://s10.postimg.org/xcaxotaqx/02_preview-veicoli-industriali_800x800_blu.jpg');
}

.box1:hover:before {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(2);
}

.box1:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">

</div>
```